# Help lines only in the lower part with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Using the tcolorbox package to produce exercises for a textbook, I use the option `invisible` to let space for students for writing their solutions. 
Now I want to use the `help lines` in overlay commands only in the lower part, and not in the upper part, so get an upper part with blank background. How can I do this?

More, can I use a more general command for `help lines` in the lower part, which inserts only horizontal lines, and not the vertical ones?

Edit: The solution given first is not useful when the exercise breaks, where we obtain the error message: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named segmentation is known.`

I give an example where I make the exercise breaked:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    segmentation style={double=white,draw=green!20!black,double distance=1pt,solid},
    lowerbox=invisible,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\end{document}
```

and its compilation:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east)` by `(interior.south west) grid (segmentation.east)`

**reedited as follows:**

1. a new command named `\myunderlay` is defined
2. two *tcolorbox* options: `underlay unbroken=\myunderlay` and `underlay last=\myunderlay` are added in place of `underlay={...}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\myunderlay}{
  \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (segmentation.east); % modified
          \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay unbroken=\myunderlay,
    underlay last=\myunderlay,
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    segmentation style={double=white,draw=green!20!black,double distance=1pt,solid},
    lowerbox=invisible,
    %savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2,
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function: 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}

\lipsum[1-3] 
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}




\tcbstoprecording


\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, but this solution is not useful when the exercise breaks, and then it gives the following error:

`! Package pgf Error: No shape named segmentation is known`

Comment: I think it maybe very helpful if you provide a reproducible example with the issue encountered!

Comment: Now with the edition of @PhelypeOleinik all is good. Many thanks for the two

Comment: It seems to me that there is some kind of confusion since it's @hafidBoukhoulda who reedited the answer to address the break's issue!